# How to cache images in watch app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I am caching image with following code - From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKInterfaceDevice/cachedImages)

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[rowData valueForKey:@"thumbnail_media_id"]];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];

            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                // add image in cache
                [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] addCachedImage:image name:url_string];

                [elementRow.rowImage setImage:image];
            });
        });
```

And when getting the image from cache checking if image name contains in

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] cachedImages];
```

then get the image with method -

```
[elementRow.rowImage setImageNamed:url_string];
```

But not able to get the cached image, any help ?

Comment: Which value is returned from `addCachedImage:name:`? It returns a boolean indicating success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache image using `NSCache` but you probably should not be using dataWithContentsOfURL.  NSURLSession has helpful caching built right in.

http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Comment: @Smith we can use NSCache in watch application ?

Comment: NSCache is in Foundation.  It should be usably pretty much from anywhere.